# Linux: Combining commands

Tags: linux, grep, sort

I am trying to find all names that containing the letter `y`. Following this, I want to sort the output of this command in reverse order and write the output to a new file.

This is my code

```
grep -ioh '[y]' names | sort -fr | > newfile
```

Comment: The syntax error aside, what is your question?

Comment: search the ‘Names’ file for all names containing the letter ‘y’. Following this, sort the output of this command in reverse order and write the output to a file called ‘Ynames’.

Comment: What do you want to sort? You say "the output of the command" but what do you want the output to be? The entire name that was matched? Only the letter `y` (which is what the current output is)? Maybe the whole line on which the name was found? Please [edit] your question and show us a few example lines from your `names` file, and then the _exact_ output you want from those example lines. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format the examples as code.

Comment: Are the names on per line or just a words with delimiters (which delimiters - space, tab, newline?)?

Answer (score 4):

The `-o` option for GNU `grep` will make the utility only return the substrings that matches the expression.  Your expression is `[y]`, which is the same as just `y`.  This means `grep` would return a list of `y` characters (and `Y`, as you use case insensitive matching with `-i`).

You furthermore have a syntax error at the end of the pipeline.  The final `|` character should not be there. Instead, the redirection should be from `sort` directly (or be replaced by the `-o newfile` option and option-argument with `sort`).

You have said nothing about the contents of the file `names`, so I'm going to *assume* that it is a file containing names, one per line.

To get all lines that contain the letter `y` (case ignored), you can use

```
grep '[yY]' names
```

or

```
grep -i 'y' names
```

Then you may sort these in reverse order, ignoring case again (although most names, I suppose, would start with an upper-case letter anyway), using `sort -f -r` as you have done:

```
grep '[yY]' names | sort -f -r -o newfile
```

or

```
grep '[yY]' names | sort -f -r >newfile
```

In this *particular* case, the ordering of the commands doesn't really matter.

```
sort -f -r names | grep '[yY]' >newfile
```

You could even write it as

```
( sort -f -r | grep '[yY]' ) <names >newfile
```

or

```
<names ( grep '[yY]' | sort -f -r ) >newfile
```

or one of many other variations on the same theme.

Comment: I figured it out guys, just before I saw your answer, Kusalananda. I would like to thank you, Bulletbob and terdon.

Comment: The ordering of the commands does matter efficiency-wise: better to `grep` then `sort` because the latter does not have cheap linear O(n) complexity like the former. Then, particularly if `names` is a huge file, it's more efficient to reduce the dataset before performing a sort algorithm on it, IMHO.

Comment: @Totor This is absolutely true.  It can also be argued that if `names` is a _huge_ file, then it should be sorted once and for all first, before using it in the first place.